# VisualFlow and Process to update custom Owner field on record that is detail of master-detail relationship to logged in user

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder

We have an object that is detail object in a master-detail relationship, but we still wanted it to have an owner field. so we created a custom field that looks up to Users. However it currently has to be manually populated everytime new record is created. What we would like to happened is that when you create a new record, the owner will automatically update to whoever is logged in. I have built this previously using a visual workflow and process combo, however I have lost access to this and cannot seem to recreate it. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you should be able to do this with only a Process Builder - no flow needed.  Create a Process Builder to be fired on record creation, and fire for the criteria you want, but then for your actions - select a Record Update and you will be able to traverse to your Owner field on the Master object and update the Owner Custom field on the Detail object.